# Regular expressions to find all none alphanumeric chars which are not in a whitelist

Tags: regex, compiler-construction

how can I write a regular expression to care about both condition:
1-(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)     (a simple variable name)
2-some string like :

```
%%
%%%
:=
()
{}
[]
<>
and ....
```

I want an expression to detect other chars except above groups

**Edited:**
I want a regular expression to just find invalid char that aren't in above groups that are alphabetic char like`[a-z]` and `:=` and...

**Edit2:**
this question is about scanner of a mini compiler for academic project and I want to find invalid char that aren't in language char and language char are all above example like all of `[A-Za-z0-9]` and all `%% [] {} <> <= >= () :=`
in other words I want a regular expression to detect all chars that aren't in language's chars.

To summarize: How can I write an expression to find all chars that aren't `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `%%` or `%%%` or `:=` or `()` or `{}` ....

Comment: If you're parsing a programming language, regular expressions are not good at this. Use regexes to tokenize and a parser to parse.

Comment: this is a project and I should use this format for it.

Comment: you have to tell us more then. Your question is hard to answer in the present form.

Comment: i add new information to it as edited part.

Comment: Add full `examples` with new information. Adding examples will actually help YOU formulate your question better, as well as helping other readers.

Comment: @sln: "formulate the question", the best therapy.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte - Perfect!

Comment: new information was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,it's something like:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9:=\]\[%{}]
```